# Why my Poseidon For Uml Garbled?

Tags: uml

I downloaded a [Poseidon for UML 8 - Installer (Community Edition 8.0.0)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXlRZ.jpg). 
When I do exit operation or some other operations, I got code Garbled Dialog as:

[image]

Comment: to Kara,I just installed it to design my class diagram or some use case.

Comment: to Kara, then what about this: http://pan.baidu.com/s/13mr2R. All dialogs have garbled!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are running Windows is in a language (eg. Chinese) that is not supported by the software. Some dialogs like Yes/No dialogs and file open dialogs have translations for other languages but the font used in the software does not display the characters correctly so you just see empty boxes.

It should be easy to guess on most dialogs what they should say, in your example the buttons probably say Yes, No, Cancel.

You can change the language in Windows to English and it should work.